# Oracle ADF Task Flow

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-adf

I am new for Oracle ADF, I was about to create unbounded task flow but I got this message "The directory must be relative to the project's HTML root.  Without this, some ADF Page Flow design-time and run-time features will not function as expected." I try to check online materials but I couldn't find any material. All suggests to put it at WEB-INF BUT I already create EO(entity Object ) and View Object (VO).

Any help appreciated.

Comment: And jsp page? there is?

Comment: Take the screenshot of the project structure and upload here

Comment: Do you have 2 seprated view controller project and model project? The first one put EO and VO, second one is for UI components, e.g., jsp, task flow.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you All, @Wanana I notice the project Structure its MVC and I follow the following link its very helpful link . The solution for my issue was I did't create the Task flow and set default event triggered when the system start. – user3710320 just now   edit